# No Windows in grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2, 15.04

I came across this really strange problem today. I had Windows 10 installed in my laptop (in Legacy Boot). I installed Ubuntu 15.04 after installation of Windows and found there was no Windows boot menu.

So, i went ahead and did a :
`sudo update-grub` hoping it'd fix it. 
The system reported it found 'Windows Recovery Environment' on /dev/sda2.

I rebooted the system and I found I still had only Ubuntu in the grub selection menu.

I double checked /boot/grub/grub.cfg. It does have a Windows menuentry, but it is somehow not getting in the boot menu.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you install with UEFI o Legacy MBR?

Comment: I used the legacy MBR.

Comment: Is the Windows partition still there? Can tou post a screenshot of Gparted of the disk?

Comment: im having the same issue. ANy fix on this?